# $\frac 00=$ ? Why It is un answerable?

Tags: arithmetic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Division by $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26445/division-by-0)

What will be the answer if zero$(0)$ divided by zero$(0)$
Why It is un answerable?

$$\frac 00=\space ?$$
Thanks in Advance,
Vicky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because any number multiplied by $0$ gives $0$. So $a \times 0 = 0$ implies that $a = \frac{0}{0}$ for any a at all. So the answer is nonsense. So we simply say that $\frac 00$ is indeterminate form.

Comment: And indeed we say that the operation of dividing by 0 is prohibited in general.

Comment: thanks :) So we should not use division by zero at any instance

Comment: No, never. This was what caused so many problems when trying to put the calculus on to a rigorous footing.

Comment: Not "indeterminate form" but "undefined". The term "indeterminate form" is used in the context of evaluating limits, but the question is just about why the arithmetic operation of division is undefined with operands $0,0$.