# What are singular value of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $
A = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{x + (\frac{3}{4} + y)i}&1&1\\
0&{(x - \frac{5}{4}) + iy}&1\\
0&0&{(x + \frac{3}{4}) + iy}
\end{array}} \right)$,  and $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.

What are singular value  of $A$?(In terms of $x,y$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the matrix is upper triangular, the determinant is just the product of the diagonal elements. Hence

$$D = \left[x + i\left(\frac{3}{4} + y \right)\right] \cdot \left [\left(x- \frac{5}{4} \right) + iy \right ] \cdot \left[ \left(x + \frac{3}{4} \right) + iy \right]$$

Setting $D$ to zero and computing the values of $x$ and $y$ will give you the zeroes.

Comment: I think you are wrong. The question is about singular values and not eigenvalues. Your solution is complex instead of non-negative.

Comment: Oh, hm, you're right. can you SVD a complex matrix in that case?

Comment: Sure, you can SVD any matrix.

Comment: @Gil A quadratic matrix is singular iff zero is an eigenvalue of that matrix.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe - Please more guide

Comment: @Undersky just read http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503585/show-that-a-matrix-a-is-singular-if-and-only-if-0-is-an-eigenvalue/503644#503644

Comment: @MichaelHoppe - Thanks, but what are singular value of $A$?(in terms of $x,y$)

Comment: @Undersky - Obviously $(0,-3/4)$, $(5/4,0)$, and $(-3/4,0)$ due to the first answer.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe - Why? (Singular value is square root of $det(A-\lambda I)=0$).

Comment: @Gil - Please more guide.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, I understand the question different. I don't think they are looking for values of $x,y$ such that the matrix is singular (i.e., eigenvalues zero), but looking for the singular values (SVD) of $A$. A straightforward solution would be taking the square root of the eigenvalues of $A^*A$, but it is kinda ugly...