# Are determinants additive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I was studying eigen values and suddenly they try to prove a property that states the only way eigenvalue of a matrix will be $0$ if the matrix itself was singular.

So, they went on to prove their statement by taking the determinant of $ A-\lambda I $

So, $ | A- \lambda I | = 0 $

Then they did this

$$ | A | - \lambda | I | =0 $$

Is this step valid? and if so what is the reason?

Another question: They tried to prove the characteristic equation for $ A-\lambda I $ and $ A^T -\lambda I $ is the same.

They took the determinant of the two matrices $ | A- \lambda I | $ and $  | A^T -\lambda I | $

Then they concluded that since $ | A | = | A^T | $ then the two aforementioned determinants should be the same. Were they using the same law?

Comment: In general determinants are not additive,. but FYI, I think the most easiest (probably most common proof aswell) that a matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda = 0$ is singular is that if it has an eigenvalue of $0$ means $\exists v \ne 0 , Av = \lambda v =  0$

Comment: @ZiadFakhoury there exists *nonzero* $v$ so that $Av=0$.

Comment: That step is not valid. If a matrix has an eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $A-\lambda I$ is automatically singular. That does not mean $|A| = \lambda$.

Comment: I general, that is wrong.  If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then $|A - \lambda I|$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, but $|A| - \lambda |I|$ is a polynomial of degree $1$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi thank you. But, then how do they proof that characteristic equation for trasnposed matrices are same :/

Comment: The determinant for transposed matrices is the same.

Comment: $(A-\lambda I)^T = A^T - (\lambda I)^T = A^T - \lambda I$ because transposes *are* additive. Then they use the rule that transposes don't change determinants.

Comment: @NinadMunshi wow! didn't see that one coming. Thank you so much ^_^

Comment: Determinates are the volume of the parallelopied defined by the vectors.  When you multiply two matrices, the unit boxes of one are replaced by the boxes of the second, and the volume of the product is the product of the volume.

Comment: Where is this from? Some more context would be helpful in deciphering that step in the proof. If it’s a proof by contradiction, for instance, the authors might have made some assumption that justifies that step. Or, it could be a typo.

Answer (score 1):

According to your explanation for the first question, it seems that the equation
$$|A-\lambda I|=|A|-\lambda |I|$$
appaers in their attempt to ensure the following statement:

> Statement 1: If $A$ is not singular, then $0$ cannot be an eigenvalue of $A$.

Statement 1 is equivalent to the following statement:

> Statement 2: If $\lambda=0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $A$ is singular.

Perhaps their proof is for Statement 2? If this is the case, then the equality holds trivially from the assumption $\lambda=0$.

As a matter of fact, the converse of Statement 2 is also correct. See
[Show that a matrix $A$ is singular if and only if $0$ is an eigenvalue.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503585/show-that-a-matrix-a-is-singular-if-and-only-if-0-is-an-eigenvalue)