# Is $\frac{0}{0}$ different from $\frac{1}{0}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, infinity

In my mind, zero divided by zero answers the question of what $a$, when multiplied with zero, equals zero:

$a * 0 = 0$

Obviously, any real number will satisfy this equation. However, one divided by zero is different. It answers this question:

$a * 0 = 1$

This is different, because there are no solutions. Both results are referred to as "undefined". To me, these two "types" of undefined are completely different. I realize that many applications don't care whether there's no results or infinite results. However, am I correct in my assumption that there are two types of undefined here? And if so, is there any terminology differentiating them that I can search for, possibly related to sets?

Question summary: Are there different types of undefined? If so, what are they?

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate. I've searched, but it's kind of hard when you don't know what you're searching for. I have read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26445/division-by-0), but it doesn't mention any specific terms.

Comment: You'll need to make your question much more specific if your want a good answer. e.g. If your question is "Are there different kinds of undefined," you should make that clear.

Comment: Your analysis is sound. One is undefined because the solution is not unique. The other because there is no solution.

Comment: You should not assume $1/0 = 0/0$ and you also should not assume $0/0 \ne 1/0$.

Comment: When this concept is introduced to K-12 students, teachers make a distinction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression $\frac{0}{0}$ and, similarly, $\frac{1}{0}$ and anything divided by zero is called "undefined" for a reason. That's because there is no defined value for the expression; it's meaningless without context.

Let's look at the expression $\frac{0}{0}$ more closely in terms of limits. I ask you these following questions:

$1.$ What is $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{x}$

$2.$ What is $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x}$

$3.$ What is $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x^2}$

All of these have an indeterminate form of $\frac{0}{0}$; however, each has a different limit. In this case, it is important to look at relative rates, i.e. how much "quicker" one becomes zero than the other.

Comment: isn't $0/0$ indeterminate and $1/0$ undefined instead of both being undefined?

Answer (score 5):

## In limits

$\frac{0}{0}$ is an [indeterminate form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).  That is, if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = 0$, then $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ may or may not be finite. User92774 has given some examples.

However, $\frac{1}{0}$ is *not* an indeterminate form.  If $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = 0$, then $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \pm \infty$.

## In computer floating-point arithmetic

In IEEE 754, 0.0 / 0.0 = [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), but 1.0 / 0.0 = $\infty$.