# Prove that in an ordered field, $0\cdot x=0$ for every $x$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

> Prove that in an ordered field $0\cdot x=0$ for every $x$.

I'm not sure how to go about proving something is true in an ordered field. What are the steps involved?

Comment: What are your axioms for "ordered field"?

Comment: That the field is ordered is irrelevant. Even that it's a field isn't important, that holds in every ring.

Comment: Useful fact: $0 + 0 = 0$, so $0\cdot x = (0+0)\cdot x$.

Comment: One of the answers to "[Fields - Proof that every multiple of zero equals zero](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911075/fields-proof-that-every-multiple-of-zero-equals-zero)" contains a proof that works just fine.

Comment: Please don't use $*$ for multiplication in mathematics. It usually signifies *convolution*, which is another beast entirely. (I fixed it for you.)

Answer (score 3):

Everyone talking about ordered fields being unnecessary and no one actually helping. Here you go:

Since $0$ is the additive identity, we have $0 = 0 + 0$. So for $x \in F$, we have

$0\cdot x = (0+0)\cdot x$.

By distributivity,

$(0+0)\cdot x = 0\cdot x + 0\cdot x$.

Whatever $0\cdot x$ is, it's an element of the field (i.e. ring), so it has an additive inverse $-(0\cdot x)$. Add it to both sides  to obtain

$ 0\cdot x + 0\cdot x + (-(0\cdot x)) = 0\cdot x + (-(0\cdot x))$

$0\cdot x = 0$.

As others have mentioned, this is perfectly true in a regular old ring. You can also prove that $x\cdot 0 = 0$ separately.

Answer (score 1):

As zeno's answer shows, the order axioms aren't necessary.  But here's a proof that uses them:

> If $0\lt0x$, then
>
> $$0x=0+0x\lt0x+0x=(0+0)x=0x$$
>
> which is a contradiction.  Likewise if $0\gt0x$.
>
> Therefore $0x=0$.

What's used about ordered fields is:

1. If $a\lt b$ then $a+c\lt b+c$ for any $c$; and
2. For any $a$ and $b$, exactly one of the relations $a\lt b$, $a\gt b$ or $a=b$ holds.

The only other field axioms being used are $0+a=a$ for any $a$ and $ac+bc=(a+b)c$ for any $a,b,c$.