# Question about limit and dividing by zero

Tags: limits

I know that the dividing by *zero* topic has been discussed in detail in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26445/division-by-0). However, I still don't quite understand how $$\frac{1}{0}=undefined$$ but  $$\lim_{n \to 0}\frac{1}{n}=\infty$$ isn't there some sort of contradiction?

Comment: But using your notation, we have $\lim_{n\to 0}\frac{1}{-n} =-\infty$, so $1/0$ is both positive and negative infinity at the same time. If that doesn't smell "undefined", then I don't know what does. Plus, we don't like to have $\infty$ as an actual function value. We put it on limits more as a shorthand for " grows indefinitely ", rather than as an actual value.

Comment: Note that in the function $$f(x)=\cases{1& if $x=0$\\0& otherwise} $$ we have $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$, because that's how limits are defined to work.

Comment: Just use Real Projective Line and the two expressions become equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a contradiction if you misunderstand the limit $\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac
{1}{x}$ to mean $\frac{1}{0}$. However, the correct meaning of limit is not just substitution, and no, there is no contradiction at all. You simply must understand that a limit (if it exists) has a precise meaning that has absolutely nothing to do (in this case) with division by $0$, only with divisions of the form $\frac{1}{x}$ for every possible **positive** value of $x$.

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't the limit mean that you keep "plugging in" larger and larger values for "n"?

Comment: no @Rzeta, not at all.

Comment: Okay this calls for a drastic review of limits on my part. Thanks for your help!

Comment: that's the spirit!