# Does $\,0\mid 0?\ $ Is $\,\text{lcm}(a,0)=0?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

1) Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Is it correct to claim that $0\mid 0$?

I guess that it is true since by definition: We claim that $a\mid b$ if there exists $c\in R$ such that $b=ac$. In our case $0=0\times 0$ so $0\mid 0$.

2) Let $R$ be an integral domain. Suppose that $\text{lcm}(a,b)$ exists! Is true that $\text{lcm}(a,0)=0.$

Indeed, $a\mid 0$ and $0\mid 0$. Let $a\mid m$ and $0\mid m$ then $0\mid m$ and we have that $\text{lcm}(a,0)=0$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: *Divisibilty* by zero is not the same as *division* by zero. You are right that $0 \mid 0$, and that $a \mid 0$ for any $a$. As a consequence, the equation $a \cdot 0 = 0$ does not have a unique solution, so $\frac{0}{0}$ is not well-defined.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26445/29335) but not really a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct.

By the way, this all makes more sense from the viewpoint of lattice theory; maybe try to get your hands on [Davey and Priestley's](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/introduction-to-lattices-and-order/946458CB6638AF86D85BA00F5787F4F4) book, which is where I learned the material.

Once you know the basics of lattice theory, simply observe the following:

- The principal ideals in a ring $R$ form a [poset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set]) $\mathrm{PrinId}(R)$, where we define $aR \leq bR$ to mean $bR \subseteq aR$, which is equivalent to $a \mid b$.
- The principal ideal $1R$ is the smallest element of this poset, and $0R$ is the greatest element.
- This means in particular that $0 \mid 0$ is true, because this translates to the order-theoretic statement $0R \leq 0R$, which is true because we're in a poset.
- If $R$ happens to be a [GCD domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain), then $\mathrm{PrinId}(R)$ will be a [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)). The $\mathrm{gcd}$ in this lattice coincides with the lattice-theoretic meet and the $\mathrm{lcm}$ coincides with the lattice theoretic join.
- This means in particular that $\mathrm{lcm}(a,0) = a$, because this translates to the lattice theoretic statement $a \vee \top = a$, where $\top$ represents the largest element of the poset, and this fact is true in every lattice, not just $\mathrm{PrinId}(R)$.

Anyway, long story short, you should learn some lattice theory and it'll all fall into place pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply! One more question: Am I right that my second question is true even in commutative ring $R$?

Comment: @RFZ, yes, this is true in any commutative ring with LCM's. Again, in this case we get a poset whose elements are the principal ideals. The existences of LCM's translates into the existence of [joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet). Since $a \vee \top = a$ holds in any poset with joins, the desired identity follows. Try having a look at the wikipedia page on meets and joins; it should be pretty enlightening. Joins are a bit like suprema from real analysis; if I have a poset $P$ with elements $a$ and $b$, their join, if it exists, is the smallest element $p \in P$ with $a \leq p$

Comment: and $b \leq p$. That is, it's the least upper bound. A simple example is this: if $S$ is a set and $\mathcal{P}(S)$ is the set of all subsets of $S$, then $\mathcal{P}(S)$ has joins and they coincide with unions. In other words, I'm saying that $A \cup B$ is the smallest subset $C$ with $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq C$. This is the most basic example, the poset of principal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ is arguably the second most basic example; in this case, joins coincide with lcm's.