# Prove that a point in a circle equidistant from any three points on the circle is the centre

Tags: circles

1. Prove that a point in a circle equidistant from any three points on the circle is the centre
2. $\frac{1-1}{1-1}=?$

Comment: For the second part: $0/0$ is not defined in mathematics.

Comment: why both terms do not get cancelled?

Comment: why answer is not 1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26445/division-by-0

Comment: @MohammadNoorAlam if $\frac 00=n$, then $0 \cdot n = 0$. How many ways can this be solved?

Comment: if a/a=1, then why not (1-1)(1-1)=1?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $p$ is a point in the plane that is equidistant (say of length $r$) to three distinct points on the circle. Then the circle at $p$ of radius $r$ intersect the original circle at three points. If two circles intersect at three points then they must be the same and hence $p$ is the center of the original circle.